# Condition making a Compact Operator have to be a finite rank operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I have tried to the following exercise :

> Let $T$ be a compact operator, X an infite dimension Banach space and suppose that there is a closed subset $M$ such that $X= Im T\bigoplus M$, then $T$ is a finite rank operator.

Now my first approach to this was that since $M$ is closed we will have that $X/M$ will be a banach space and we know that $X/M \cong Im T$ but this is an algebraic isomorphism I am not sure we get an homeomorphism of spaces so that we could conclude that $Im T$ is a Banach space. If we have that $Im T$ we will have that this will be an open map from $X$ to $ImT$ and so $T(B_X(0,1))$ will be open in $Im T$ and so we have that for this to be relative compact $ImT$ has to have finite dimension. Now I am not sure that we will that $Im T$ will be a banach space because I think we get an algebraic isomorphism, will this be the case or do we have that $Im T$ is in fact a banach space? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your reference material, $X=\operatorname{Im}(T)\oplus M$ may already imply that $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ is closed.  Where is this exercise from?

Comment: Yeah this exercise is from an old exam of my functional analysis course, I just assumed that he meant only the algebraic decomposition because the previous exercise was to show that if $Im(T)$ is closed then it has finite rank so this one would be trivial.@Aweygan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition of a compact operator and a continuous operator is again compact.

Now consider $\pi \circ T$, where $\pi \colon X \to X/M$ is the canonical projection. By the above, it is compact, and by the assumption $X = \operatorname{Im} T \oplus M$ it is surjective. Also, $X/M$ is a Banach space, whence $\pi \circ T$ is open. Thus $X/M$ is locally compact, hence finite-dimensional.

Comment: Ah I see thanks , so I could not assume that $Im T$ would be a banach space right ?

Comment: That is something we need to deduce (follows from finite-dimensionality). If we know a priori that it's a Banach space, the exercise becomes trivial.